# Changing Stroke color in HTML 5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graphics

I'm trying to draw a circle, kind of a clock, i start at point p1 and draw an arc in black using the canvas 2d context, when i reach the point p1 (complete circle tour) i change color to white, and continue to draw, that should give it an effect like if the black arc is being erased, however this doesn't work as expected, because when i change the context's color, everything change...

how to keep the first circle, in a color, and draw another one on topof it with different color, without changing the color in the whole scene ?

here's my attempt

```
<!DOCTYPE html />
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var i = 0.01;
        var Color = "Black";
        var x = 75;                // x coordinate
        var y = 75;                // y coordinate
        var radius = 20;                    // Arc radius
        var startAngle = 0;                     // Starting point on circle
        var anticlockwise = false; // clockwise or anticlockwise

        function draw() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                ctx.beginPath();
                var endAngle = i; // End point on circleMath.PI + (Math.PI * 5) /

                if (Math.floor(endAngle) >= 6) {
                    i = 0.01;
                    if (Color == "Black") {
                        Color = "White";
                    } else {
                        Color = "Black";
                    }
                }

                ctx.strokeStyle = Color;
                ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise);
                ctx.stroke();

                i = i + 0.05;
                //document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = Math.floor(endAngle) + " " + Color;
    }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="window.setInterval(function(){draw()},100);">
<canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
<span id="display"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're having a little trouble with your angles. You're essentially redrawing the arc from 0 to your `endAngle` every time. So at the end when endAngle is greater than 6 you're redrawing from 0-6 with a white arc.

The easy fix is to just set `endAngle = 0.01` when you reset `i`. You may also want to update your `startAngle` on each iteration to be the end of your last arc, just so that it doesn't draw over itself all the time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8afe/) to play with this, using @Shaded's suggestion of updating startAngle.  It fixes your issue, but presents a few others, namely: anticlockwise doesn't work with this (we'd need to swap endAngle and startAngle), and it seems that the lighter color isn't overwriting the darker one, but blending with it.  Also, I changed your condition from `Math.Floor = 6` to the more accurate `if endAngle >= 2 * Math.PI`, to avoid a gap in the drawing.

Comment: thanks both of you. here is an update, but yes it's true Scott, it colors are blending :)   http://jsfiddle.net/Wzt38/

Comment: Fyi, it's not a blending issue but an antialiasing one.  Still odd that it doesn't perfectly overwrite, though.

Comment: correct..i will post an update when i figure this out, not sure if i need to accept the answers now.

Answer (score 2):

Using Shaded's answer, you could do the following:

```
if (Math.floor(endAngle) > 6.0) {
    i = 0.01;
    endAngle = i;
    startAngle = 0;
    if (Color == "Black") {
        Color = "White";
        ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    } else {
        Color = "Black";
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    }
}

ctx.strokeStyle = Color;
ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise);
ctx.stroke();

startAngle = endAngle - 0.1;
```

Because the white will anti-alias with the black behind it, you'll get the jaggies at the edges if the line widths are the same. Increasing the line width alleviates this issue.

**EDIT:** Updated to remove excessive over-painting as per Shaded's comments.

Comment: I tried this, it seems the problem still persists with the black line still being visible :\

Comment: Odd, Seems to work fine here [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XGundam05/fHUKa/). I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Hmm... that's strange I'm also on Chrome and your fiddle works for me too... I can't seem to spot the difference!

Comment: Ahhh, it's because you still keep the startAngle set to 0. I was updating it to the end angle to prevent needless over painting, but I guess it helps in this situation.

Comment: That would make sense, and I didn't think of that :\ `startAngle = endAngle - 0.1;` Also works, as you get just enough over painting to cover it up.